# Running an R-script from C#

Tags: c#, r

I have the following `R` script and `C#` program that is used as an example of calling R from C#. If I run the script from within R-GUI, I see the expected `output`. However, if I run it from within C# as below, I get no output. I tried moving the R script inside the C# executable `directory`, and this doesn't work either. I tried running `Visual Studio` as `Administrator`, again no output.

Not sure what I am doing wrong:

R code:

```
# Gradient Boosting model with gbm
# Turn off library warning messages
suppressWarnings(library(gbm))


# gbm result for simulated data
get_gbm <- function()
{
    set.seed(123)
    a <- sample(1:10, 250, replace = T)
    b <- sample(10:20, 250, replace = T)
    flag <- ifelse(a > 5 & b > 10, "red", ifelse(a < 3, "yellow", "green"))
    df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b, flag = as.factor(flag))

    train <- df[1:200,]
    test <- df[200:250,]

    mod_gb <- gbm(flag ~ a + b,
                  data = train,
                  distribution = "multinomial",
                  shrinkage = .01,
                  n.minobsinnode = 10,
                  n.trees = 100)

    pred <- predict.gbm(object = mod_gb,
                        newdata = test,
                        n.trees = 100,
                        type = "response")

    res <- cbind(test, pred)
    return(res)
}

# need to call function to get the output
get_gbm()
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rmainpath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3";
        var rpath = rmainpath +  @"\bin\Rscript.exe";

        var mainGoogleDrivePath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Google Drive";
        //var scriptpath = mainGoogleDrivePath + @"\repos\rsource\Script.R";
        var scriptpath = mainGoogleDrivePath + @"\Projects\RFromCSharp\RFromCSharp\bin\Debug\Script.R";
        var output = RunRScript(rpath, scriptpath);

        Console.WriteLine(output); // output is empty
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string RunRScript(string rpath, string scriptpath)
    {
        try
        {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = rpath,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(scriptpath),
                Arguments = scriptpath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            using (var proc = new Process { StartInfo = info })
            {
                if (false == proc.Start())
                    throw new Exception("Didn't start R");

                return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the script from R, are you running `source()`? Your script doesn't seem to explicitly `print()` anything so when running the code non-interactively I don't think anything will print. Try changing the last line to `print(get_gbm())` if you are expecting the result to be printed to the console.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking re: source() - I gave the exact way  I am calling the R script from C# in the code above. Adding print(gbm()) doesn't do anything.

Comment: You said, "If I run the script from within R-GUI". It's unclear exactly what you mean by that. Did you copy/paste into the console or something. or did you run `source("Script.R")`?  The latter of which is more closer to what happens when you run `Rscript`. R behaves differently when run interactively vs not.

Comment: In the R-GUI, I open the script, select all the txt, then hit the run button. Works perfectly. This code calls Rscript.exe, which is probably the same program except no GUI - just a console. The one thing that might be going wrong is, I installed gbm package in the GUI, but don't know if the Rscript also sees that package?

Comment: I found almost exactly the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138322/run-rscript-using-processstartinfo-from-c-sharp

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. It runs just fine for me when I change the paths for my computer. As long are your GUI and RScript share the same `.libPaths()` it should be able to find the package. Maybe you also want to redirect standard error to see if you are getting an error message. Or try running Rscript from the command line directly to make sure it works.

Comment: The problem is the space in the path to the r-script. Now works!